# PHP Search and Get Matches in XML

Tags: php, xml

I am working on a project and i need to search data in xml and find matches:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result>
 <QueryDetails>
  <Count>8947</Count>
  <MaxPage>448</MaxPage>
 </QueryDetails>
 <Products>
  <Product>
   <Code>1002132</Code>
   <Code_Hash>3e575f41e33eef1fe1d2c6f9d8b10a2f</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1002132%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=3e575f41e33eef1fe1d2c6f9d8b10a2f&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[GP17R8H-BU1 9V 170 mAh Şarj Edilebilir Pil]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>32.99</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>32.99</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Piller ve Şarj Cihazları]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Piller ve Şarj Cihazları]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Gp</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/3e575f41e33eef1fe1d2c6f9d8b10a2f/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1002165</Code>
   <Code_Hash>61a86fb6fd5de8682c9c1cd6c88eaacb</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1002165%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=61a86fb6fd5de8682c9c1cd6c88eaacb&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[GPCR123A 3V Lithium Photo Pil]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>14.99</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>14.99</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Piller ve Şarj Cihazları]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Piller ve Şarj Cihazları]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Gp</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/61a86fb6fd5de8682c9c1cd6c88eaacb/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1002168</Code>
   <Code_Hash>b5666221b1a0db5a58e36d6869379bf8</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1002168%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=b5666221b1a0db5a58e36d6869379bf8&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[GPCR2 3V Photo Lityum Pil]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>14.99</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>14.99</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Piller ve Şarj Cihazları]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Piller ve Şarj Cihazları]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Gp</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/b5666221b1a0db5a58e36d6869379bf8/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1002424</Code>
   <Code_Hash>6e5896508651c998ebce0fdcee205db6</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1002424%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=6e5896508651c998ebce0fdcee205db6&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[DSC INK/Paper Mürekkep + Fotoğraf Kağıdı KP 36IP]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>49.99</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>49.99</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Diğer Fotoğraf Aksesuarları]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Diğer Fotoğraf Aksesuarları]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Canon</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/6e5896508651c998ebce0fdcee205db6/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1002502</Code>
   <Code_Hash>41a68a156dc4784d83bf302b6b383723</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1002502%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=41a68a156dc4784d83bf302b6b383723&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[EF 85mm 1,8 USM Lens]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>1789</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>1789</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Lens]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Lens]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Canon</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/41a68a156dc4784d83bf302b6b383723/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1002504</Code>
   <Code_Hash>64cdae0a1ffb8546a750753bf49361a4</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1002504%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=64cdae0a1ffb8546a750753bf49361a4&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[EF 100mm 1:2,8 USM Makro Lens]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>2239</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>2239</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Lens]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Lens]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Canon</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/64cdae0a1ffb8546a750753bf49361a4/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1003046</Code>
   <Code_Hash>599fa513fe22b69f7a9f0793850df3e8</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1003046%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=599fa513fe22b69f7a9f0793850df3e8&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[HTFS 2 BQ Ev Sinema Sistemi Hoparlör Ayağı Siyah]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>499</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>499</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[HiFi Mobilyalar]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[HiFi Mobilyalar]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>HARMAN KARDON</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/599fa513fe22b69f7a9f0793850df3e8/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1003248</Code>
   <Code_Hash>286950f46badbebca643eff0668b250a</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1003248%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=286950f46badbebca643eff0668b250a&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[81700 Medistim Elektronik Ağrı Kesici Mini Tens Cihazı]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>99.99</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>99.99</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Medikal Cihazlar]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Medikal Cihazlar]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Medisana</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/286950f46badbebca643eff0668b250a/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1003337</Code>
   <Code_Hash>e3834464bda14258cb5d1245662f6bec</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1003337%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=e3834464bda14258cb5d1245662f6bec&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[ESAM 6600 PRIMADONNA]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>4199</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>4199</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Espresso Kahve Makineleri]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Espresso Kahve Makineleri]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>DE LONGHI</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/e3834464bda14258cb5d1245662f6bec/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1003575</Code>
   <Code_Hash>8169d972359015e0a40907882bb9dcf4</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1003575%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=8169d972359015e0a40907882bb9dcf4&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[81244853 MPZ 9 Citormatic Pulp Control Narenciye Sıkacağı]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>109</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>109</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Narenciye Sıkacakları]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Narenciye Sıkacakları]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Braun</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/8169d972359015e0a40907882bb9dcf4/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1003756</Code>
   <Code_Hash>309a8305ce2a6a51a00b3edce0ecad1e</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1003756%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=309a8305ce2a6a51a00b3edce0ecad1e&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[75048089 Yedek Başlık Floss Action EB25-2]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>30.99</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>30.99</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Ağız Bakım Ürünleri]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Ağız Bakım Ürünleri]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Braun</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/309a8305ce2a6a51a00b3edce0ecad1e/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1003768</Code>
   <Code_Hash>a4414db3ff3aa8f268b0a322ed070647</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1003768%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=a4414db3ff3aa8f268b0a322ed070647&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[Yedek Başlık Çocuk EB102K]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>30.99</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>30.99</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Ağız Bakım Ürünleri]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Ağız Bakım Ürünleri]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Braun</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/a4414db3ff3aa8f268b0a322ed070647/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1004075</Code>
   <Code_Hash>1fd69247c8a69dd7d8f880425af7db5a</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1004075%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=1fd69247c8a69dd7d8f880425af7db5a&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[EM 30 Abdominal Karın Kası Kemeri Siyah Bordo]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>249</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>249</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Egzersiz Ürünleri]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Egzersiz Ürünleri]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Beurer</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/1fd69247c8a69dd7d8f880425af7db5a/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1004081</Code>
   <Code_Hash>9b5e4e12ca0fd8d603cd2b1ca48dd28e</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1004081%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=9b5e4e12ca0fd8d603cd2b1ca48dd28e&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[HM 21 Sıcaklık Sensörü]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>19</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>19</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Hava Nemlendirici & Temizleyiciler]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Hava Nemlendirici & Temizleyiciler]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Beurer</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/9b5e4e12ca0fd8d603cd2b1ca48dd28e/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1006156</Code>
   <Code_Hash>54f30389b2fe3be27dabc57f412d8b71</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1006156%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=54f30389b2fe3be27dabc57f412d8b71&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[HR1560/40 400 W Paslanmaz Çelik Çırpıcılı El Mikseri]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>159</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>159</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Blender & Mikser]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Blender & Mikser]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Philips</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/54f30389b2fe3be27dabc57f412d8b71/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1006179</Code>
   <Code_Hash>0c5bd274ea037cacfbf51c9ea567c2a2</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1006179%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=0c5bd274ea037cacfbf51c9ea567c2a2&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[HR1396/55 400 W Doğrayıcı]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>129</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>129</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Doğrayıcılar & Rondolar]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Doğrayıcılar & Rondolar]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>Philips</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/0c5bd274ea037cacfbf51c9ea567c2a2/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1006272</Code>
   <Code_Hash>8a3f8dfceeba5020bdd8841f49c0c606</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1006272%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=8a3f8dfceeba5020bdd8841f49c0c606&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[341464 HP DJ 5550 için Siyah Kartuş]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>43</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>43</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Kartuşlar]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Kartuşlar]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>PELIKAN HARDCOPY</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/8a3f8dfceeba5020bdd8841f49c0c606/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1006304</Code>
   <Code_Hash>cdd97fe1f774d1012d6402e89c1ea1a1</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1006304%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=cdd97fe1f774d1012d6402e89c1ea1a1&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[PC-302RF Faks Filmi 559012]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>19</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>19</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Kırtasiye Ürünleri]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Kırtasiye Ürünleri]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>PELIKAN HARDCOPY</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/cdd97fe1f774d1012d6402e89c1ea1a1/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1006305</Code>
   <Code_Hash>86f43baef2539cb058abb08b5c447e0e</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1006305%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=86f43baef2539cb058abb08b5c447e0e&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[PC-202RF Faks Filmi 559036]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>19</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>19</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Kırtasiye Ürünleri]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Kırtasiye Ürünleri]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>PELIKAN HARDCOPY</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/86f43baef2539cb058abb08b5c447e0e/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <Code>1006306</Code>
   <Code_Hash>6d7659037b631ab678a54b3c24cbb21e</Code_Hash>
   <Offer><![CDATA[Mediamarkt]]></Offer>
   <URL><![CDATA[http://ad.reklm.com/aff_c?offer_id=1209&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediamarkt.com.tr%2Fcatentry%2F1006306%3Frbtc%3Drek%257coaf%257c%257c%257cp%257c%257c%26utm_source%3Dreklamaction&aff_sub4=feed&aff_sub5=6d7659037b631ab678a54b3c24cbb21e&aff_id=2762]]></URL>
   <Title><![CDATA[PC-72 RF-402 Faks Filmi 548993]]></Title>
   <FullDesc><![CDATA[]]></FullDesc>
   <ShortDesc><![CDATA[]]></ShortDesc>
   <ListPrice>9</ListPrice>
   <SalePrice>9</SalePrice>
   <Currency>TL</Currency>
   <DiscountRate>0</DiscountRate>
   <MainCategory><![CDATA[Kırtasiye Ürünleri]]></MainCategory>
   <ChildrenCategory><![CDATA[]]></ChildrenCategory>
   <Categories>
    <Category><![CDATA[Kırtasiye Ürünleri]]></Category>
   </Categories>
   <Colors>
    <Color><![CDATA[]]></Color>
   </Colors>
   <Variants/>
   <Sizes>
    <Size><![CDATA[]]></Size>
   </Sizes>
   <Stock>1</Stock>
   <Gender>N</Gender>
   <Brand>PELIKAN HARDCOPY</Brand>
   <Extra/>
   <Images>
    <Image>http://feed.reklamaction.com/image/large/6d7659037b631ab678a54b3c24cbb21e/eba3b814bbc3ff57cf00204f38cefdd4?id=0</Image>
   </Images>
  </Product>
 </Products>
</Result>
```

I need get matches of  
Php Code:

```
<?php
$catalog = simplexml_load_file("media.xml");
$urunler = $catalog->Products;
$urun = $urunler->Product;
$aranacak = "Pil";
foreach ($urun->Title as $Xml) {

if (preg_match("/".$aranacak."/", $xml)) {

$matches[]=$Xml;

}

}

print_r($matches);
?>
```

But it doesnt working. If anybody can help me i will very happy because its my project.

Comment: ha ha . *I cant add xml code because there are some errors in stackoverflow* i think you don't know how to add it .

Comment: I can't see `CR_NAME` in the xml anywhere

Comment: There is no key with name `CR_NAME`.

Comment: Sory its fixed @JYoThl i know how to add but if i add it need more text because code is to long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/807384)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadXML($string);//your xml string goes here

$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$results = $domXPath->query("//Products/Product");
$aranacak="Pil";
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    $textContent=$domXPath->query(".//Title",$result)->item(0)->textContent;
    if (preg_match("/$aranacak/",$textContent))
    {
        $matches[] = $textContent;
    }
}

print_r($matches);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => GP17R8H-BU1 9V 170 mAh Åžarj Edilebilir Pil
    [1] => GPCR123A 3V Lithium Photo Pil
    [2] => GPCR2 3V Photo Lityum Pil
)
```

Comment: It printed all listings. I want only matches.

Comment: Can you share your expected output? in your post for a single field

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => GP17R8H-BU1 9V 170 mAh Åžarj Edilebilir Pil
    [1] => GPCR123A 3V Lithium Photo Pil
    [2] => GPCR2 3V Photo Lityum Pil
)

Comment: It worked can ı ask how to remove Array() and [0] [1] tags ?

Comment: @BatuhanOsmanTaşkaya you want to get only last one. `GPCR2 3V Photo Lityum Pil`?

Comment: I want all without Array tags

Comment: @BatuhanOsmanTaşkaya You can use `echo implode(" , ",$matches)` on the very last of my post.

Comment: Thanks :) Its last question how i get ListPrice of matches.

Comment: @BatuhanOsmanTaşkaya for that you can change it to `$textContent=$domXPath->query(".//ListPrice",$result)->item(0)->textContent;` and also remove preg_match condition

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
$catalog = simplexml_load_file("http://batuhantaskaya.com/xml/media.xml");
$urunler = $catalog->Products;
$urun    = $urunler->Product;
$aranacak = "Pil";

foreach ($urun as $key=>$val) {

    if (preg_match("/".$aranacak."/", $val->Title)) {
     $matches[] =  (string) $val->Title;
     $lprice[] =  (string) $val->ListPrice;
    }
}


$result = array_combine($matches, $lprice);

print_r($result);
```

=========================================================================

***Output***

```
Array
(
    [GP17R8H-BU1 9V 170 mAh Åžarj Edilebilir Pil] => 32.99
    [GPCR123A 3V Lithium Photo Pil] => 14.99
    [GPCR2 3V Photo Lityum Pil] => 14.99
)
```

Comment: How i get ListPrice of the matches? Can help this